# Change textsize in Android button if text is too long

Tags: android, button

I have buttons with fixed size, but the text is changed time to time.
Sometimes the text is too long to fit in the button, and for these cases I want to use a smaller textsize.

How can I change the button textsize if text is too long?

(One solution could be to test how many characters that can be used with the normal textsize, and then change textsize if the length is larger than this baseline. But I was hoping for more dynamic approach.)

Answer (score 1):

1)Measure the button.
2)Using the same font, use Paint.getTextBounds() to get the width.
3)Compare the size of the button to the width.  You'll probably need to add some extra room on both sides for padding, but this is going to be a bit of an estimate anyway.
4)If the text was too big, reduce the size of the text (on the Paint object) and goto 2.
5)Now that you have a working size, call setTextSize on the button.

Note:  if you're doing this for an AlertDialog, you need to do it after the button exists-  I've had problems with step 1 depending on where I put this function, but its been so long I forgot the exact issue.  I think I had to do it after calling show?

Answer (score 1):

You can Extend Button Class to something similar to [AutofitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/grantland/widget/AutofitTextView.java)

Comment: @EirikO please tick the answer if it helped you.